# DOCBOOK to EPUB File Size

Tags: epub, docbook

Some eBook reading devices (like older Kindles) perform better with OEBPS/Text file sizes in the 350KB range. When you go over that, page load and scrolling can be a miserable user experience.

Question: If you have a large text, 4 MB for example---Will the DOCBOOK to EPUB publishing flow put that into OEBPS/Text that as a monolithic 4MB file, or will it split it into smaller files for you?

If it splits the file, does it repair the anchor IDs to reflect the new file name?

I couldn't find the answer to this at docbook.org.

Comment: Well, give it a try yourself, I suggest...

Comment: I don't have it installed or know how to use it (yet). I'll install and learn it if I know it will work. But I don't want to go through the learning curve to find out in the end that it won't suit my needs. So was hoping someone here knew from experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Question: If you have a large text, 4 MB for example---Will the DOCBOOK to EPUB publishing flow put that into OEBPS/Text that as a monolithic 4MB file, or will it split it into smaller files for you?*

The "DocBook to EPUB publishing flow" (DocBook XSL) will split the input XML into smaller output files.

This process is called "chunking" and is described in detail here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Chunking.html (this is a section from the book [DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/index.html)).

> *If it splits the file, does it repair the anchor IDs to reflect the new file name?*

I am not completely sure what you mean by "repair the anchor IDs", but the chunking process does ensure that cross-references and entries that go in to *.opf and *.ncx files are correct.

EPUB is one of many output formats that can be created from DocBook sources. If you have never used DocBook XSL before, you should read "DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide" (see link above). This book does not cover EPUB output specifically (it was written before the EPUB stylesheets had been developed).

DocBook XSL provides stylesheets for both EPUB 2 and EPUB 3 (most of the effort goes into EPUB 3 these days):

- README for EPUB 2: http://sourceforge.net/p/docbook/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/xsl/epub/README.
- README for EPUB 3: http://sourceforge.net/p/docbook/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/xsl/epub3/README.

Comment: I researched your comments. Thanks. With some preparation of the XML, it seems I could get the chunking to work for me. A challenge I encountered with DOCBOOK was setting up an environment to make it work. If there were only a Virtual Machine stack out there to make it work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practices are to create separate HTML files for chapters (and sometimes sections).

As long as your file separates things into one of these elements, you can use chunking to produce the results you want.

All the anchor IDs will work like a charm. Even the indices will work!